# Is a question about how to recover a saved password off-topic?

Tags: discussion

We had a question today about if it was possible to recover saved passwords from Firefox on Linux.  While I certainly thing the question of IF it is possible is on topic as it is asking about a security concern.  If the user want's to know how to recover the passwords, is it then off topic?

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I think at that point it would be off topic since it is talking about how to use a particular piece of software and access data in it.  It's also effectively something the software is supposed to do (since you can't use a saved password without the system being able to access it.)  It's not really a security question anymore, but then again, I suppose best ways to try and crack a weak encryption would be, so I'm not sure if it is on-topic or not.  I wanted to see what other people's thoughts were on something like this.

Comment: To my mind, it boils down to whether it's a question of tools or techniques. Questions regarding *use of tools* to recover passwords would be better served on SuperUser, while *techniques* to recover passwords should be on-topic here (or possibly at Crypto.SE). Once we go from "how" to "what" the topicality changes.